# Unable to run prisma code in docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, next.js

I am able to connect and use prisma in my nextjs project on my local but when i try to use same code using dockerfile.
I am getting error. I am using the following `Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:16-slim
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y openssl

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ENV PORT 3030

COPY ["package.json", "package-lock.json", "./"]
COPY prisma ./prisma/

RUN npm install --production --silent && mv node_modules ../
RUN npx prisma generate

COPY . .

RUN npx next build

EXPOSE 3030

CMD ["npx", "next", "start"]
```

When code reaches prisma line application crashes with error. Error message is not clear as it returns errorCode and client as Object.

```
try {
        const { id } = req.body as any;
        const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
            where: { sfid: id },

        });

    } catch (error) {

        res.status(200).json({ id: 'error', cart: error, products: [] })

    }
```

This line `const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({` crashes the application in docker.

Comment: What is the actual error message?  The Docker image build stage runs in a more-isolated-than-usual environment and can't connect to a database or a GraphQL server; do you need to run this generation step outside of Docker and commit the resulting files to source control?

Comment: i am able to connect to remote database in docker container but unable to access it through prisma. generating outside can work too in my case

Comment: Same issue. It also happen in github codespaces.

Answer (score 3):

Used the following docker file and its working now

```
FROM node:lts
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y openssl

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ENV PORT 3030

COPY ["package.json", "package-lock.json", "./"]
COPY .env ./.env
COPY prisma ./prisma/

RUN npm install --production --silent && mv node_modules ../

RUN npm i -g prisma

COPY . .

RUN npx prisma generate --schema ./prisma/schema.prisma
RUN npx next build

EXPOSE 3030

CMD ["npx", "next", "start"]
```

Answer (score 1):

when you build the app the docker network didn't exist yet, you should build the app and start it using seperate file.

here is the example of my dockerfile for next js using prisma:

```
FROM node:18-alpine

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /app

# Bundle files
COPY . .

#Update npm 
RUN npm install -g npm@latest

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install

# Expose port 3000
EXPOSE 3000


# create seperate cmd in order to make the image completed and the network exist, this is usefull for prisma to access db
# Start app
CMD source migrate-and-start.sh
```

migrate-and-start.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
npm run build
npx prisma generate
npx prisma db push
npm run start
```

Answer (score 0):

Do database run on same host as your docker image ?
What address do you use ?

In case of localhost and 0.0.0.0 => you are looking for database inside you docker container, not full host server